# What is the correct way to import modules from a module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been using `Python` for my ML/DL projects. However, I recently started a project in `JavaScript` to visualize my works.

I would like to import modules (.js files) from the `main.js` for conciseness. *(I had already checked [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453282/whats-right-way-to-import-a-module-javascript-node-js), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988268/correct-way-to-reference-modules-from-other-modules-in-typescript), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988268/correct-way-to-reference-modules-from-other-modules-in-typescript) but couldn't get the right answer for my case.)*

I have JS files like below which should be imported like this to put all the helper functions in `util.js`

> main.js --> tree.js, polygon.js, graph.js, ... --> util.js

Currently, I am able to import the models from `main.js` like below. However, I am not able to import `util.js` module from the imported modules (`tree.js`, ...).

index.html

```
<script type="module" defer src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
import Tree from './tree.js';
var tree = new Tree(...);
...
```

tree.js **[QUESTION!]**

```
import * as util from './util.js'; <-- ("This is not properly working")
util.helperFunc();
...
export default Tree;
```

util.js

```
function helperFunc() { ... }
export {helperFunc, ...};
```

1) Is the above structure violates the JavaScript / TypeScript convention? (It looks right to me as a Python user.)

2) How can I import `util.js` from `tree.js` (`tree.js` is imported from `main.js`)?

3) I saw a lot of answers which use `node.js`, is it not recommended to just use a simple server like below?

> python3 -m http.server 8080

Comment: Please understand my situation before telling this question as a duplicate. Thank you. :)

Comment: Your `util.js` should export something, if you want to be able to import it elsewhere

Comment: Thanks, I actually exported all functions but forgot to include them in the question.

Comment: In general you will need to import `util` separately in all the places you need it. The interpreter will make sure that multiple imports do not actually cause multiple network request or multiple compilation for `util.js` but the other imports merely use the cached version. This is generally considered good practice because you are documenting in your source where objects/functions/classes come from..

Comment: .. But if you **really** want to import util via tree you will need to re-export everything in tree.js eg: `export helperFunc; export default Tree`

Comment: Thank you very much. The comments are very helpful.